# How to write a Scene Heading for on the way somewhere

Tags: screenwriting

I am writing my very first script and I have so much to learn.

For now, I want to know how to write a scene heading where the character is on the way to a location.

```
EXT. SEASIDE - DAY
...
character one is doing the stuff
...

EXT. ON THE WAY TO SEASIDE - DAY 
...
character two is going toward the seaside where character one is.
```

How should I write the scene heading for scene two where character two is on the way to the seaside?

Answer (score 1):

The scene has to happen somewhere, so it is e.g. on a train / in a car - anything that allows the character to get there. That is what will be the descriptor for the scene.

```
INT. CAR - DAY
MIKE
How long will it take us to get to the sea?
```